# PHP Regex - Issue with forward slashes and alternation

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, magento

I have a series of URLs like so:

```
http://www.somesite.com/de/page
http://www.somesite.com/de/another
http://www.somesite.com/de/page/something
http://www.somesite.com/de/page/bar
```

I need to search the block of text and pull the language and am using a regex like so:

```
/(de|en|jp)/
```

I'm trying to find and replace, via `preg_replace` and including the forward slashes:

```
/de/
/en/
/jp/
```

However, this doesn't work and does not include the slashes. I've tried escaping the slashes with `\`, `\\`. I've tried placing the needle in `preg_quote` but this breaks the alternation.

I feel like I am missing something very simple here!

**edit:**

Full function call:

```
preg_replace("/(de|en|jp)/", "/".$newLang."/", $url);
```

--

*(tagged magento and wordpress as I am trying to solve an issue with unifying the navigation menu when both CMSes are multilingual)*

Comment: Can we see the whole call to `preg_match` or whatever function you are using?

Comment: Show the actual regex. Remember that `/` are the default regex delimiters, so you may have to have a pattern more like `|(/(de|en|jp)/)|` instead.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I've edited with the full function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use slashes as delimiters, but you have to have some delimiter. Try this:

```
if( preg_match("(/(de|en|jp)/)",$url,$m)) {
    $lanuage = $m[1];
}
```

Comment: No he has not, they are there, he used forward slashes as delimiters, he is just not matching the slashes. ```preg_match('/\/(de|en|jp)\//', $url, $m)``` :P

Comment: @Geoffrey No, I'm using parentheses as delimiters. This is perfectly valid and useful, since it helps remind me that item 0 of the match array is the whole match.

Comment: Okay, rolled it back to what I originally typed. Next time, Frits, don't edit what's already correct!

Comment: @Kolink, that worked perfectly, can you explain what exactly happened? Was it the outer parentheses that tells php that within is a regex?

Comment: @waffl As I understand it (someone correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not a php pro), the outer parentheses are acting as delimiters (you need to use delimiters in php to wrap your regex). The one you had was using the forward slashes as delimiters, which then reduced your regex to only `(de|en|jp)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different delimiter, such as %.

```
if (preg_match('%/(de|en|jp)/%', $url, $match)) {
    $lang = $match[1];
}
```

That should help you, just modify what you have :).